# How can we set second picklist value dynamically with string value is know in CRM Dynamics 4.0

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, workflow-activity

I have two pick-list in Car details entity. I'm setting the **Model (cir_model)** Picklist value with from the input parameter (that is CrmNumber) of Custom Workflow activity and it's working as expected, and the second pick-list **Marque (cir_marque)** will be set logically using the **Model** pick-list.

Logic should be if **Model** is set to 'Ac Ace' then **Marque** should be set to 'Ac'. Take value 'Ac' using Split() from the string 'Ac Ace'.

Normally in C# this can be done easily but in CRM 4.0 how this can be achieve (How I'll set 'Ac' to Marque)

[image]

```cs
public static DependencyProperty modelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("model",  
typeof(int), typeof(CreateCardetails));
[CrmInput("Model")]
public int model
{
    get
    {
        return (int)base.GetValue(modelProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(modelProperty, value);
    }
}

public static DependencyProperty ContactProperty =   
DependencyProperty.Register("Contact", typeof(Lookup), typeof(CreateCardetails));

[CrmInput("Contact ID")]
[CrmReferenceTarget("contact")]
public Lookup Contact
{
    get
    {
        return (Lookup)base.GetValue(ContactProperty);
    }
    set
    {

        base.SetValue(ContactProperty, value);
    }
}

protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext  
executionContext)
{
        //Create an car details record which will be linked to the contact record
        DynamicEntity cardetails = new DynamicEntity("cir_cardetails");

        cardetails["cir_carsdetailsid"] = Contact;

        //Setting the picklist value of Model

         Picklist modelPickList = new Picklist();
         modelPickList.Value = model.Value;
         cardetails.Properties.Add(new PicklistProperty("cir_model",modelPickList));

  /*
      Here the logic should be done for setting Marque (cir_model) value 
         Picklist marquePickList = new Picklist();
         marquePickList.Value = ???
         cardetails.Properties.Add(new PicklistProperty("cir_marque",marquePickList));
  */

       //Creating the car details record
        Guid carkey = crmService.Create(cardetails);
}
```

How we can set the **Marque** value logically, I have left the code blank for this like below

```cs
/*
      Here the logic should be done for setting Marque (cir_marque) value 
         Picklist marquePickList = new Picklist();
         marquePickList.Value = ???
         cardetails.Properties.Add(new PicklistProperty("cir_marque",marquePickList));    
*/
```

Please arrange to help me out on this, all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no language CRM 4.0, in CRM 4.0 you code in c#. The only thing that change is the way you work with new types.

In Workflow you don't work with controls, you work with entities and the related attributes. So you "just" need to get the attribute cir_model, do a subtring and find the available options in Marque and set the corrected value. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677091.aspx) sample from SDK.

Comment: See RetrieveRequest request for a specified record, that's fine. I wanted something there are two pick-list with different values. But their values are logically set. i.e 1 picklist has Ferrari, but second picklist may any one of "Ferrari 360", "Ferrari 220", etc. I'm setting  "Ferrari 220" to 2nd picklist but then I want to set Ferrari to 1st picklist. I wanted a CRM code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript or C# (Plug-In, Workflow) to accomplish this.  There are some considerations to think of when choosing which approach to use.

If you want the user to be able to see the result in real time (when they select) then you can use JavaScript.

If you don't care for the user to see the result, or there is data coming in from an outside source (not the user form), then think about using a plugin.

I don't think you should have to use a WF to do this, plugins are just as easy to write and will happen instantaneously instead of waiting for the async process to complete.

Comment: If I know the code to use in Plugin to achieve this then I can use the same in Custom workflow activity. Do you have any suggestion on how to get all drop-down of any pick-list of entity using C# code in plug-in. If you have any idea please post it here. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can retrieve all the options for an attribute by retrieving the Metadata for that attribute.  Cast the AttributeMetadata to a PicklistAttributeMetadata object and it will have a list of options that have a label and value.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890660.aspx

Comment: Do you want the results to be visible on the form while the user is changing it? If so, you can't do it with plugins or workflows, you need to use javascript for that.

Comment: No not like that. I'll pass input on first pick-list the value like "Ferrari 360" (index value), so then it should set "Ferrari" (but here don't know the index, get all the list items, compare and set to it) to second pick-list.